# Conditionally Revalue a Factor in R

Tags: r, recode

This answer may very well be obvious (I hope it is), but I kept only finding convoluted solutions. What I'd like to do is conditionally revalue a factor based on the levels of another factor.

Here's an example using the mtcars dataset:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$am) # examining the levels
levels(mtcars$gear)
# [1] "3" "4" "5"
levels(mtcars$am)
"0" "1"
```

Now among those cars with a gear level of "5", how can I assign a new "gear" level of "6" 
to those with an "am" level of "1", while retaining the factor levels "3","4","5" for "gear"? This is a much simpler example, but given the complexity of my dataset I'd prefer to keep the vectors as factors (and not transform to numeric and back, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "6" level in gears to begin with, so you need to create one:

```
levels(mtcars$gear) <- c(levels(mtcars$gear), "6")
```

You can then conditionally assign with the `[<-` function:

```
mtcars$gear[ mtcars$am==1 ] <- "6"
table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$am)

     0  1
  3 15  0
  4  4  0
  5  0  0
  6  0 13
```

You cannot assign values to a factor variable if there is no corresponding 'level' in the factor attributes.

Comment: Beautiful, simple solution! (My Rube Goldberg-esque workaround entailed converting to numeric and back.)

Comment: I have found factors to be quite error-prone. I generally prefer to leave everything as character or integer untul ready to actually do the analysis. Terry Therneau, whom I greatly respect, says that the Mayo Clinic mandates `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: Good workflow tip on leaving factors until the end! I'm curious -- in general what have you found error-prone with respect to factors in R?

Comment: They are really (constrained) integer vectors. If I could only remember to always use `as.character()` around them I'd be a happier person.